# Star sizing not working in WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my XAML:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

It's not what I expect.  I want grid row #0 to take 25% of the vertical space, grid row #1 to take 60% and grid row #2 to take the remaining 15%.  I thought my `RowDefinition` elements did that, by totalling 100%.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: outer StackPanel gives Grid minimal space to arrange elements. it doesn't allow Grid to stretch

Comment: @ASh Is it fixable? How can I get the StackPanel to give the Grid max space?

Comment: use a different container, which will allow grid to stretch, or set some fixed Height for grid, or bind grid Height. possible fix depends on the layout which you need in the ned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackPanel with vertical Orientation can offer child elements infinite vertical space to position themselves. When Grid is offered infinite height or width, it chooses to treat `*` as `Auto` (if I correctly understand [`Grid.MeasureOverride` implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Grid.cs,450)) and doesn't stretch.

Limit Grid Height in some way: set fixed Height, bind Height to some value (e.g. some other element ActualHeight), use different parent container which has finite size

Answer (score 2):

Remove/delete the outer stack panel and this will do what you want.

Also if you want margin put it on the grid instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your outer `StackPanel` will help.

---

`Grid` of WPF has several unexpected behaviors. In your case, it's the unexpected behavior of `double.PositiveInfinity` measure length.

I've posted the unexpected behaviors here: [The undefined behaviors of WPF Grid (the so-called bugs)](https://walterlv.github.io/post/the-bugs-of-grid-en.html). And I've written a new one in [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Grid.cs).